Query Manager Delete option restriction
How to restrict the Delete option from Work with Query Manager Queries in iSeries V7.4
The DLTQMQRY has been set up with the proper permissions to avert this happening however users are able to run reports from the Query Manager itself having sometimes running the option 4 (delete object) by accident. Please notice the delete option referred here is different than the delete function used in SQL statements.

Use object authority to prevent the user from deleting the query object from the library.
